# Suppressing the “Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS” message

Tags: linux, java, environment-variables, openjdk

I'm using _JAVA_OPTIONS to set some defaults for Java on RHEL. It works fine but now every time I start java I get the following message

```
 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -foo -bar -baz
```

is it possible to keep the options but suppress the display of this message.

Answer (score 15):

Java is often called with absolute paths like `/usr/bin/java`, which makes this answer useless in some cases, and requires more to make it work in others.

That solution I found requires writing a wrapper shell script that redirects STDERR through a filter removing the offending line. It has to be placed in the `$PATH` before the java binary it wraps and be called with plain `java`, `which java` or similar (or your tool has to be configured to use it)

It relies on the bash ability to create a subshell with parentheses `(command)`, and redirect java’s STDERR to its STDIN `command1 2> >(command2)`. Finally, the process in the subshell needs to redirect its filtered input to STDOUT again so that java programs can still use STDERR.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/java "$@" 2> >(grep -v "^Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:" >&2)
```

Comment: Probably terrible practice, but it's for a docker image and I got tired of all the red during `docker build` -- but I renamed `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java` to `java2` and put a modified version of this script in there as `java` (with `chmod +x`).  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

Or you can put this in your shell startup / profile files:

```
_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS="$_JAVA_OPTIONS"
unset _JAVA_OPTIONS
alias java='java "$_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS"'
```

Comment: that only works when directly invoking `java ...` through the command line. all java invocations through scripts or other parent processes will be unaffected

Comment: well, you can change /bin/java to be a shell script that does the same thing if you really want to.

Comment: even if you don't it will unset the options, so other commands will be affected too. It will silence them by not passing them any options :).

Answer (score 2):

This message is output by all standard versions of Java since (I think Java 5).  It is certainly present in the source code from Java 6 through Java 15.

It is output by the `java` command  when it sees that the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` or `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable is set and when the user is not privileged.  The behavior is hardwired, and the `java` command doesn't provide a way to suppress it.  (If you want more precise details, look at the `arguments.cpp` file.)

People have requested that Oracle add an option to suppress the message:

[JDK-8039152 : Need a way to suppress message when picking up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8039152)

but this has been closed as WON'T FIX.

---

First of all, it is important to understand why this message is output.  According to bug report's analysis:

> "So that leaves adding an option to suppress the message. Yes, we could do this, but is it a good idea? **The reason that the message is issued is that the feature being used is dangerous and the VM should warn about it.**
>
> I strongly recommend that we don't try to change this behavior.
> 03-04-2014"

In short, the message is a WARNING that something potentially dangerous may be happening.  Something that could cause `java` to behave in unexpected (and possibly even insecure) ways.

---

So what can you do to make the annoying message go away?

The best solution is to not use those variables.  Unset them!  There are other ways to pass command options to the `java` command that are less dangerous.  If the annoying output is coming from some application that relies on those variables ... raise a bug report for the application.

There are other possible solutions; e.g. filtering the message out of the error stream, or expanding `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` into the `java` command line (see other answers).

- I recommend that you **DO NOT** do either of these things.  Why?  Because by suppressing the message you are disabling an important safety feature in the `java` command.
- And if you do decide to suppress the message, **DO NOT** do it by replacing the standard `java` command with a shell alias or a wrapper script.  That is really asking for trouble.

Comment: `It is output by the java command when it sees that the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS or _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable is set and when the user is not privileged. ` What kind of privilege would a user need?

Comment: I imagine they mean privileged like an administrator or root user.

Comment: What sort of trouble does a wrapper script invite?

Comment: *"What sort of trouble does a wrapper script invite?"* - Security vulnerabilities, etcetera.